# How to script a global keyboard shortcut in MacOS

Tags: macos, keyboard, command-line, script

I want to configure a global keyboard shortcut in MacOS using a script.

Specifically, I want to set the "Move focus to next window" to ⌘⇧§ (since I have a Swedish keyboard and the default ⌘⇧` has a tendency to insert backquotes all over the place)

So I want the setting to end up like this [image: Keyboard shortcuts with "Move focus to next window" focused]

I have tried this command

```
defaults write -g NSUserKeyEquivalents '{ "Move focus to next window"="@§"; }'
```

Inspired by [this](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20131123074223584) and [this](https://www.raizlabs.com/dev/2015/02/how-to-script-os-x-keyboard-shortcuts/) instruction. But it does not work.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you won't just double-click "Cmd-§" at the right of your highlighted line and input your desired shortcut ?!? Doesn't this work with you? Oh, sorry, just noticed you want to have a script doing this for you.

Comment: Great question. That said, it can be helpful to be more specific when saying something doesn’t work: https://itdidnt.work/

Comment: @AlanH. Good point. It simply did nothing at all, no shortcut was changed.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you want to set the "Move focus to next window" to `⌘ ⇧ §` you'll obviously also need ***two*** modifiers along with the § key. (Your screenshot is contradictory to this, though.)

Your script has to contain an additional "$" here: `'{"Move focus to next window"="@$§";}'`.
Maybe this will work?