# How can I run a script to add keyboard shortcuts on macOS?

Tags: command-line, automation, preferences

See also: [How to script a global keyboard shortcut in MacOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/334683/how-to-script-a-global-keyboard-shortcut-in-macos)

I like to maintain some scripts I use to set up new Macs the way I like them. One thing I would like to automate is the setting of some keyboard shortcuts — such as [changing the Safari "Quit" command from ⌘Q to ⌥⌘Q](https://alanhogan.com/tips/reduce-accidental-safari-quits).

Per advice [here](https://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20131123074223584), I tried running the following in the Terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.safari NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Quit Safari" -string "@~q"
```

However, quitting and re-opening Safari and System Preferences shows *no difference* after running the above command, although it *appears* to have worked if you look at the output of `defaults read com.apple.safari`.

Using the UI under System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts works as expected, causing the Quit Safari menu item to gain a modified keyboard shortcut.

How can I successfully script this change?

Comment: Try using `-app Safari` instead of `com.apple.safari`. And make sure Safari is quit before you run the command.

Comment: Hi @alan-h did you ever get this to work? I tried the same but didn't get it to work. Setting up the shortcut via System Preferences works flawlessly though.

Comment: No such luck, @tobias.